# Why does MSTest.TestAdapter adds its DLLs into my NuGet package?

Tags: nuget

I have NuGet package with some custom testing utilities. It's project is referencing `MSTest.TestFramework` and `MSTest.TestAdapter` NuGet packages, and corresponding dependencies are specified in nuspec file. Files section only specifies pdb file of project itself to be added.

Yet, I'm constantly getting DLLs related to `MSTest.TestAdapter` in `content` folder of NuGet package. Why does this happen? I can't figure out by the documentation. Can I somehow configure dependencies to not include any files?

My nuspec looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>TestUtils</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>TestUtils</title>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Test utilities</description>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="MSTest.TestFramework" version="1.1.18" exclude="contentFiles"/>
      <dependency id="MSTest.TestAdapter" version="1.1.18" exclude="contentFiles"/>
    </dependencies>   
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\$configuration$\$id$.pdb" target="lib\net461"/>
  </files> 
</package>
```

Comment: Can you show us your `.nuspec` file? Are `MSTest.TestFramework` and `MSTest.TestAdapter` the only nuget packages installed in the project?

Comment: There are several other NuGet packages installed. Weird thing is that they are not specified as dependencies, yet they are never getting into content folder. Only MSTest projects are, despite having same reference setting.

Comment: Oh, small update, only TestAdapter DLLs are getting into NuGet

Comment: Try removing the `<dependencies>` element. `MSTest.TestFramework` and `MSTest.TestAdapter` are nuget packages references, so they should be displayed as a nuget dependency.

Comment: BTW check Nuget Package Explorer, it's a nice tool to check if your nuget packages were created correctly. Maybe you could post a screenshot using this tool? See https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer

Comment: I have added <dependencies> element in hope it will remove unnecessary dlls. Btw, I've found out why dlls are getting into my NuGet. That's behavior of TestAdapter.prop file. Removing import of prop file from csproj of my NuGet has solved this issue.