# Can I work around adding these .dlls when installing NuGet package?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, nuget

I started off by reading through this suggested question similar to mine, but there was no resolution: [Why does MSTest.TestAdapter adds its DLLs into my NuGet package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50905870/why-does-mstest-testadapter-adds-its-dlls-into-my-nuget-package)

**Quick Problem Description**

I wrote a NuGet package, and each time I install it, `NUnit` and `NUnit3TestAdapter` `.dll`'s get added to the project I installed on. I want to find a solution that fixes this issue.

**Repro steps**

I have pushed two git repositories that reproduce the issue I am describing.

`ClientLibrary` / `MainFramework` (project from which I generated NuGet package) - https://github.com/harbourc/client-library-repro-nuget-issue

`TargetProject` (project that package is to be installed on) - https://github.com/harbourc/target-project-repro-nuget-issue

You can clone both repositories, restore their NuGet packages, and reproduce the issue as follows:

1. Locate ClientLibrary.1.0.0.nupkg in client-library-repro-nuget-issue/ClientLibrary/
2. Open package manager console for target-project-repro-nuget-issue and run

```
Install-Package C:\Path\To\client-library-repro-nuget-issue\ClientLibrary\ClientLibrary.1.0.0.nupkg
```

3. Note the `NUnit` and `NUnit3TestAdapter` `.dll`'s that are added into `TargetProject` -- even though `TargetProject` already has `NUnit` and `NUnit3TestAdapter` installed.

**Longer Overview**

I have created my own NuGet package for internal use, called `ClientLibrary`, and I am attempting to install it on to another project, called `TargetProject`. Here is a quick breakdown of the structure:

- `FullSolution.sln`

  - `MainFramework.csproj`
  - `ClientLibrary.csproj` --> `.nupkg` generated from this

Separate project:

- `TargetProject.sln`

  - `TargetProject.csproj` --> install `.nupkg` onto this

`ClientLibrary` has a reference to `MainFramework`, and uses many methods from `MainFramework`.

When installing `ClientLibrary.1.0.0.nupkg` onto `TargetProject`, the following `.dll`'s are getting added to `TargetProject`:

```
nunit.engine.api.dll
nunit.engine.dll
NUnit3.TestAdapter.dll
NUnit3.TestAdapter.pdb
```

If I delete these `.dll`'s, everything works fine, because `TargetProject` already has those packages installed anyway. They are not necessary, it's just annoying to have to delete them when installing.

Here is how I am adding `ClientLibrary` NuGet package to `TargetProject`:

1. Build `ClientLibrary` and `MainFramework` projects to generate their .dlls
2. Change directory into `ClientLibrary` folder and run `nuget spec`

`.nuspec` file is generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>ClientLibrary</id>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <title>Client Library</title>
    <authors>Myself</authors>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Client library for interacting with my application.</description>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.7.2" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

3. Run `nuget pack -IncludeReferencedProjects` -- Because `ClientLibrary` has a dependency on `MainFramework` (and several other packages used by `MainFramework`)
4. Navigate to `TargetProject`, open Package Manager Console
5. Run `Install-Package C:\Path\To\ClientLibrary.1.0.0.nupkg`

Installation runs successfully, and then those `.dll`'s I am complaining about get added.

**Problem:**

`MainFramework` has `NUnit` and `NUnit3TestAdapter` NuGet packages installed. `ClientLibrary` **does not.** So, the `.dll`'s seem to be added because they are  installed on `MainFramework`, but NOT installed on `ClientLibrary`. (Remember, `ClientLibrary` references `MainFramework.dll`.)

There are **other** packages installed on both `MainFramework` and `ClientLibrary`, and these do not have `.dll`'s that get added to `TargetProject` upon installation, so I am assuming issue is caused by having packages present in `MainFramework` but NOT in `ClientLibrary`.

I believe I can "fix" this issue by installing `NUnit` and `NUnit3TestAdapter` onto `ClientLibrary`, but `ClientLibrary` doesn't actually use those packages at all, so it seems unnecessary.

How can I install `ClientLibrary` onto `TargetProject` without including the `NUnit` and `NUnit3TestAdapter` `.dll`'s, and without having to install `NUnit` and `NUnit3TestAdapter` onto `ClientLibrary`? If possible, I would like to tell `ClientLibrary.1.0.0.nupkg` to use the `NUnit` and `NUnit3TestAdapter` packages that are **already** installed on `TargetProject`.

If the answer is "Not possible", that is fine, but I would like an explanation -- my overall goal for this question is to gain a better understanding of how NuGet and dependencies work, and understand why this has been an issue in the first place. Thank you for reading.

Comment: You will have to provide sample projects to illustrate the behavior.

Comment: @LexLi I have updated my project description with two sample repositories that illustrate the behavior, along with repro steps.

Comment: The code shows a bad aproach to have NUnit dependencies in MainFramework.csproj. Can you move them to a separate unit test project, such as MainFramework.UnitTest.csproj?

Comment: That makes sense -- `ClientLibrary` only uses some parts of `MainFramework`, so `MainFramework` can certainly be split into `MainFramework.Framework` and `MainFramework.Test`, where the `NUnit` dependencies only exist in `MainFramework.Test`, and `ClientLibrary` only utilizes `MainFramework.Framework`. Thank for the analysis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, it's best practice to keep all of your tests and corresponding NuGet packages in their own project. Then make sure none of the projects reference the test project.

[image]

On the **don't** side, Client Library will include the NUnit dlls because they were added to a project that Client Library references.

Whereas on the **do** side, Client Library will not include the NUnit dlls because neither reference the test project.

Comment: Thank you for the breakdown and explanation — I implemented this practice by splitting up my project like you and another user have suggested. This feels like much better practice than what I was previously doing, and my issue has also been resolved.